# MANIFEST file processing in JBoss 6

Tags: ejb-3.0, manifest, jboss6.x

I have an .ear file that contains:

- a jar file a.jar with some EJBs whose manifest file refers to jar b.jar in its class-path.
- a jar file b.jar with other EJBs.

This deploys correctly in JBoss 5. However, when trying to deploy in JBoss 6, I get a:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=SMS-ear.ear,jar=SMS-ejb.jar,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.ejb3.common.registrar.spi.DuplicateBindException: Cannot install org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.factory.session.stateless.StatelessSessionLocalProxyFactory@248fd67f under name "ProxyFactory/my-ear/MyEJB/local" as there is already an existing object there:
```

Where MyEJB ejb belongs to b.jar jar file. If I remove the b.jar entry from the a.jar Manifest file, everything works fine. I am pretty sure the EJB is not duplicated and there are not other EJBs with the same name.

Why does JBoss try to bind EJBs that are referenced from a manifest file a second time?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe entries in manifest are only useful for things that are not also deployed? I always leave the manifest empty. It doesn't seem to be really needed in modern Java EE, but when it does contain sonething it usually gives problems.

Comment: Getting rid of the Manifest files just worked! Thanks.